# Random loop works as planned but gets stuck on specific random number after a few calls

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

Using css and html I created 13 objects that look like boxes that each have a unique background color. Then added some random color changing functionality with javascript.

What I wanted to happen: after you click any of the 13 boxes, every box turns a 'new' color. This 'new' color will be randomly chosen from the initially fixed colors for each box. And this would go on forever.

What happened: when clicking boxes they do change color like I wanted, but after clicking only ~5-10 times they would have all turned the exact same color.

How do I get the function to keep on going and not stop at a certain color?

I probably messed up the for loop/all of javascript but can't figure it out. Any help greatly appreciated.

Here's my full code: https://codepen.io/zaemees/pen/roGgGV

Some code:

html:

```
<div class="aqua1 specs"></div>
<div class="chartreuse1 specs"></div>
<div class="deeppink1 specs"></div>
<div class="dodgerblue1 specs"></div>
<div class="gold1 specs"></div>
<div class="indigo1 specs"> </div>
<div class="lightpink1 specs"></div>
<div class="mediumpurple1 specs"></div>
<div class="coral1 specs"></div>
<div class="springgreen1 specs"></div>
<div class="red1 specs"></div>
<div class="peachpuff1 specs"></div>
<div class="deepskyblue1 specs"></div>
```

js:

```
var bloop = document.getElementsByClassName('specs');

for (var i = 0; i < bloop.length; i++){
  bloop[i].onclick = function() {
    for (var i = 0; i < bloop.length; i++){
   bloop[i].style.backgroundColor = window.getComputedStyle(bloop[Math.floor(Math.random()*13)]).getPropertyValue('background-color');
  }
 }
}
```

Comment: Hi, and welcome to SO.

You are picking from your random set, but you are not picking exclusively so it may occur you pick one more than once. Whlich leads to even a higher chance picking it more often in the next generation until there is only one choice left :)

@CertainPerformance - just hit enter instead of ctrl enter my bad :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code's main problem is that you are not preventing the same color from being selected multiple times. When you run it the first time, there is a high likelihood that at least one of your colors will be chosen twice. Think of it as simply selecting a number between one and ten at random. It is very difficult to randomly choose a different number ten times and never repeat.

Therefore, when you run your function again you have changed the backgroundColor property of each box, and some of them will have the same color, i.e. you do not have 13 different colors to choose from anymore. This means the second time your function runs you have fewer choices, and this continues and continues until you end up with only one or two possible colors to choose and every box ends up with the same color.

One way to prevent this is to have an array of your choices and remove your choice from the array whenever you select it. This will prevent duplicates, and is how most card dealing programs work so two people don't both get dealt a queen of hearts. Try this example:

```js
var bloop = document.getElementsByClassName('specs');

for (var i = 0; i < bloop.length; i++) {
  bloop[i].onclick = function() {
    var colours = ['aqua','chartreuse','deeppink','dodgerblue','gold','indigo','lightpink','mediumpurple','coral','springgreen','red','peachpuff','deepskyblue'];
    for (var i = 0; i < bloop.length; i++) {
      var rando = Math.floor(Math.random()*colours.length)
      bloop[i].style.backgroundColor = colours[rando];
      colours.splice(rando, 1);
    }
  }
}
```

```css
.specs{
  display:inline-block;
 height:100px;
 width:100px;
 border:3px solid white;
}

.aqua1{
 background-color:aqua;
}

.chartreuse1{
 background-color:chartreuse;
}

.deeppink1{
 background-color:deeppink;
}

.dodgerblue1{
 background-color:dodgerblue;
}

.gold1{
 background-color:gold;
}

.indigo1{
 background-color:indigo;
}

.lightpink1{
 background-color:lightpink;
}

.mediumpurple1{
 background-color:mediumpurple;
}

.coral1{
 background-color:coral;
}

.springgreen1{
 background-color:springgreen;
}

.red1{
 background-color:red;
}

.peachpuff1{
 background-color:peachpuff;
}

.deepskyblue1{
 background-color:deepskyblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="aqua1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="chartreuse1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="deeppink1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="dodgerblue1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="gold1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="indigo1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="lightpink1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="mediumpurple1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="coral1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="springgreen1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="red1 specs">
 
</div>

<div class="peachpuff1 specs">
 
</div>
<div class="deepskyblue1 specs">
 
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this is exactly what I needed and you provided such a good explanation! Thank you so much for helping me :)

Comment: @Zae No problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I completely understand this code, but from what I do comprehend, you are using the variable 'i' twice in both for loops. I don't know if this is intentional, but changing the nested variable 'i' to a 'j' should do the job. I hope that helps!

Comment: At first glance it may look like its nested, but actually hes iterating over all elements to apply the onclick. And in every onclick lambda(which has its own scope) he iterating over all blobs, so its ok.

Comment: oh, alright. Then this question is not my area of skills. Good luck!